# How to block the sharepoint page people.aspx for a user group?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, permissions

In my SharePoint 2010 application, I want to give the visitors group no persmission to the "_layouts/people.aspx" page. Is this possible? And how? Thanks.

Comment: What steps did you try already. Did you try googling "sharepoint block people.aspx"?

Comment: Yes, one option is to deny all users with the web.config. But what I want to know is if there is an option with standard SharePoint permission functionality. Sorry for the short question.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by myself. I gave the group a restricted read permission and then they cannot view people.aspx pages etc.